Demonstrate that $\ell^p$ is not closed in $\ell^q$, with $p < q$.
Working with the following definition of vector spaces:
$$
\ell^p = \left\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \; \middle| \; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p < \infty \right\}
$$
Let $x \in \overline{\ell^p}$ (the closure of $\ell^p$), I want to show that $x \notin \ell^p$ but that $x \in \ell^q$.
Let
$$
x_n = \left( \frac{1}{n^{1 + \frac{1}{m}/p}} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},
$$
I believe it is clear that $x_n \to x$, where
$$
x = \left( \frac{1}{n^{1/p}} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.
$$
However, $x^p = \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge in $\ell^p$. But it happens that $x^q = \left( \frac{1}{n^{\frac{q}{p}}} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in $\ell^q$.
This is my attempt, but I fail when trying to formalize the demonstration of the following statement:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n^{1 + \frac{1}{m}/p}} - \frac{1}{n^{1/p}} \right)^p  \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad m \to \infty.
$$
I cannot eliminate the dependence on (n) (using the formal definition of limit $\varepsilon$) for each term.
Could you help me?

You are talking about the closure of $\ell^p$ where?

The exercise asks to prove that $\ell^p$ is not closed in $\ell^q$, so I understand that we take the closure and we have to show that there is an element in $\overline{\ell^p}$ that is not in $\ell^p$ but it is in $\ell^q$

Are we supposed to guess that?

Isn't that the definition of being closed in a space? (Using the sequential characterization)

A subset $S$ of a metric space $M$ is closed in $M$ if and only if every sequence of elements of $S$ which converges to an element of $M$ actually converges to an element of $S$, indeed. But there has to be a space $M$ to begin with.

In your example you should denote the elements of the sequence by $x_m,$ as $m$ is the parameter.
Another example is  $$x_n(k)=\begin{cases}k^{-1/p}& k\le n \\ 0&k>n\end{cases}$$ Then $x_n$ is convergent in $\ell^q$  to $x=\{k^{-1/p}\}_{k=1}^\infty\in \ell^q\setminus \ell^p.$

How do you prove that the sequence $x_{n}$ converges with the norm of $\ell^p$ to the sequence $x$?

The sequence $x_n$ is not convergent with respect to the norm in $\ell^p,$ as $x\notin \ell^p.$ The convergence holds with respect to any $\ell^q$ norm for $q>p.$

Thank you so much
